# Not able to understand debounce parameters in rxjs

Tags: rxjs6, debouncing

I wanted to understand the intellisense displayed in the visual code which got me more confused

[image]

```
debounce(
durationSelector: (value: {}) => SubscribableOrPromise<any>
): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<{}>
```

from the above example, I think I understood the following:

1. `debounce` is the name of the function
2. `durationSelector` is a function which that a single parameter:

   a. `value` which takes Object as parameter

   b. `SubscribableOrPromise<any>` is the type that the function is going to return
3. `MonoTypeOperatorFunction<{}>`, not able to understand how a function can return `MonoTypeOperatorFunction<{}>` when it already returns `SubscribableOrPromise<any>`, this is where I am confused and not able to understand

Comment: It means a subscribable or a promise. A subscribable is something you can subscribe to, something that has a `subscribe` method. Or if you're asking about the `<any>` part, see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html.

Comment: debounce takes an object which returns SubscribableOrPromise ? then what is MonoTypeOperatorFunction

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/debounce.ts

Comment: Do you actually mean [`object`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#object)? And what do you mean *"what is `MonoTypeOperatorFunction`"*? It's unclear whether you don't understand TS declarations, or the API of the tool you're trying to use, or both.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, yes, debounce will take an value of type Object, right

Comment: As to the other part of your question, have you looked at [the definition](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/8f7d7fbf0ecb13b9b9f7736674796752349cb7d2/src/internal/types.ts#L12) to find out what it is? The clue's in the name: `export interface MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> extends OperatorFunction<T, T> {}`

Comment: i understood this part, ie.
(value: {}) => SubscribableOrPromise<any> but i am not able to understand MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> this

Comment: What do you mean *"not able to understand"*? You're not expected to be able to divine meaning just from studying the characters in the name, you need to look at how it's defined. Also please note that adding on additional questions once you've got answers is bad form for Stack Overflow - see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318890/pattern-of-you-answered-my-question-ok-yet-i-will-not-accept-the-answer-unti

Comment: If I've misunderstood your question, then please [edit] to clarify. But don't keep tacking on bonus questions in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> not able to understand how a function can return  `MonoTypeOperatorFunction<{}>` when it already returns `SubscribableOrPromise<any>`

That's **not** what is being described here, you don't have one function that returns `MonoTypeOperatorFunction` and also `SubscribableOrPromise`. You have **two functions**:

1. `debounce`; and
2. the `durationSelector` argument to `debounce` (which may be anonymous in your code).

`debounce` returns `MonoTypeOperatorFunction<{}>`, so the result can be passed to `pipe` (which takes `OperatorFunction`s, of which that's a subtype).

`debounce` requires *the function as you're passing* as an argument to it to return `SubscribableOrPromise<any>`, the line:

```
(value: {}) => SubscribableOrPromise<any>
```

is the declaration of the *argument*, `durationSelector`; it's a [function type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html).

I'd recommend reading up on *"higher-order functions"*, as that's a really important concept to understand if you're going to use RxJS.

Answer (score -1):

The single parameter for `debounce` looks like a function reference written in lambda form:

```
(value: {}) => SubscribableOrPromise<any>
```

The part before the arrow `=>` signifies the function parameters. The part after the arrow is the return type. `SubscribableOrPromise` should mean that your return type should contain a `then` function of a Promise object or a `subscribe` function used in [RxJs](http://reactivex.io/)

Try a function like this:

```
function toPromise(value) {
    return Promise.resolve(value);
}

// code in between
.debounce(toPromise);
```

This simply returns the value as an ES6 promise.
Change the `toPromise` to whatever you want the content of the function to be.

Comment: so (value: {}) => SubscribableOrPromise<any>, this will take a value of type Object and return SubscribableOrPromise type, right? then what is the meaning of MonoTypeOpertorFunction<{}> which can be seen in the intellisense

Comment: so the `SubscribableOrPromise` type should be returned by the function you use as the parameter to `debounce` (the one you will have to implement). The `MonoTypeOpertorFunction` is the return type of the `debounce` function itself.

Comment: You should be able to read the definition of that type by nagivating to `debounce`'s declaration, as it should be mentioned there as a return type. You could read that and figure out what it's used for by what members it contains.

Comment: i have just updated my question, could you please have a look at it @Andor Baranyi